# lambda expression, anonymous function delegates in C#

Tags: c#, .net

1. do all anonymous functions need to be typed with delegate keyword? for example we have a Customer class,

   ```
   delegate(Customer a)
   {return a.name == "Michael";}
   ```

Is this anonymous function

```
    (Customer a)
    {return a.name == "Michael";}
```

a function or a delegate or both?

2. do all  lambda expression also Predicate delegate by default? for example, we have a List of Customer, which is listCustomers, if we want to use TrueForAll function to see whether all customers called "Michael", we can just type as:

   ```
   listCustomers.TrueForAll(x => x.name == "Michael);
   ```

But TrueForAll takes Predicate as parameter, as we know Predacate is a delegate, which means "x => x.name == "Michael" is also a Predicate delegate by default?

Comment: The second code block is not an anonymous function. In fact, it isn't anything - that code won't compile.

Comment: For the question #2, lambda expression doesn't have a type but it can be implicitly converted to a delegate if delegate type can be inferred. In this case, the delegate type is `Func<Customer, bool>`.

Answer (score 2):

Forms of anonymous delegates:

```
// A: C# 2.0... No one uses it in new developments since years
delegate() { }

// B: C# 3.0 and above
() => { }
```

Why can I set an anonymous delegate to a given delegate?

```
Action a1 = () => Console.WriteLine("hello world");
Action<int> a2 = number => Console.WriteLine(number);
Func<bool> f1 = () => true;
```

This is called *delegate type inference*.

In summary, if the right side of an assignment fulfills the signature of the left side (i.e. *the delegate type*), the right side is infered as the type of the left side. This is also true for method parameters.

In the other hand, it's not the same a lambda expression than a delegate with lambda syntax:

```
Expression<Action> expr1 = () => Console.WriteLine("hello world");
Action a1 = () => Console.WriteLine("hello world");
```

The first is [an expression tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx), which is a data structure similar to an abstract syntax tree that can be used to extract info from the epxression and its childs, while the later is a delegate.

Expression trees can be compiled into delegates:

```
Action a2 = expr1.Compile();
a2();
```

## Further reading

- [Lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)
- [Delegate Type Inference in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/noahc/2008/09/23/delegate-type-inference-in-c/)